# Display Username in Navigation Bar

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

Curently i'm doing a Node JS System which will display username and roles in navigation bar. I felt it is hard for me everytime i using GET request i need to include find by session ID in my Code. Is there a better solution?

**Example of Get Request.**

```
router.get('/admin_user',mid, function(req,res){
  User.findById(req.session.userId).exec(function (error, user) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      console.log(user);
      User.find({},function(err,users){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('admin_content/admin_user',{'users':users, user:user});
      });
    }
  });

});
```

**Dashboard Interface**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <%- include('layout/head.ejs') %>.
    <body class="sb-nav-fixed">
        <%- include('layout/topbar.ejs') %>.
        <div id="layoutSidenav">
            <%- include('teacher_content/sidenav_admin.ejs') %>.
            <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                <%- include('teacher_content/dashboard.ejs') %>.
                <%- include('layout/footer.ejs') %>.
            </div>
        </div>
                <%- include('layout/js.ejs') %>.
    </body>
</html>
```

**Sidebar Interface**

```
<div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
    <nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
        <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
          <div class="nav">
            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Main Menu</div><a class="nav-link" href="/admin">
              <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>Dashboard
            </a><a class="nav-link" href="admin_user">
              <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-female"></i></div>User Management
            </a><a class="nav-link" href="timetable">
              <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></div>Annual Time Table
            </a><a class="nav-link" href="classroom">
              <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></div>Classroom
            </a><a class="nav-link" href="subject">
              <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></div>Subject
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sb-sidenav-footer">
          <div class="small">Welcome</div>
          <div class="small"><%= user.name %></div>
          <div class="small" class="capitalize"><%= user.roles %></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: what else were you thinking of doing to get the current user's context/state?

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get("/navbar",(req,res)=>{
const user = req.user.id;
pool.query('SELECT *FROM cust where id=$1',[user],(err,data,rows)=>{
    //when done wiyt connection,release it
    
    if(!err){
        res.render('navbar',{title:'User List', data: data.rows});
    }else{
        console.log(err);
    }
//console.log('The data from car_details',data)  
});
})
```